# Not enough rights to add an object in Algolia Laravel

Tags: laravel, algolia

I have a problem with using Algolia. Working with database but i can't save it in to API Algolia.com. I tried to search through google but i didn't get any results for this problem.

My controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $role = new Role;

    $role->name = $request->name;
    $role->save();
}
```

My model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    use Searchable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    /**
     * Get the index name for the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function searchableAs()
    {
        return 'roles_index';
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to save the data? Is there any error message given?

Comment: @NicoHaase Hi. Error is:

AlgoliaSearch \ AlgoliaException (400)
Not enough rights to add an object near line:1 column:181.

Save in to database working but i can't add record in API algolia.

Comment: @NicoHaase In document laravel, by default, when i add new a record, alogoli will automatically add in algolia.com.

Answer (score 11):

In you env file, make sure you are setting the **admin key** as the `ALGOLIA_SECRET`.

By default, Algolia gives you different key:

- Search key, which can only perform search (read) operations.
- Write key, which can index (write) data.
- Admin key, which can do everything. This is the recommended one for Laravel Scout.

Please note that **only the search key** can be passed to your frontend, if you use [Vue InstantSearch](https://community.algolia.com/vue-instantsearch/) for instance.

[image: Screenshot Algolia Keys in the dashboard]

Please let me know if that solved your issue.

Comment: this solved my problem and you saved my day thank you